# Two-dimensional array for Google Scatterplot doesn't build correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization, quotes

I am trying to create a Google scatterplot using my own data. The example from Google looks like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Age', 'Weight'],
      [ 8,      12],
      [ 4,      5.5],
      [ 11,     14],
      [ 4,      5],
      [ 3,      3.5],
      [ 6.5,    7]
    ]);
```

Each element in the array represents a point in the plot. In my code, I have two arrays (one for x values, one for y values). I want to combine these two arrays so that they fit to the example above. My code looks like this:

```
      var n50 = ${n50Values};
      var contigs = ${contigValues};
      var dataArray = [[]];
      dataArray[0] = ["n50" + ", " + "Number of contigs"];
      for (var i = 0; i < n50.length; i++){
         dataArray[0].push([n50[i] + ", " + contigs[i]]);
      }
```

Note: I create the script in Groovy, hence the ${} expressions.
When I print the array it outputs the following:

```
[["n50, Number of contigs"], ["136431, 712"], ["203520, 267"], ...
```

How can I get the right quotes for my first entry and remove the quotes for the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this simple script (i never ever try to learn Groovy, so i hope it works):

```
  var n50 = ${n50Values};
  var contigs = ${contigValues};
  var dataArray = [[]];

  var headline = new Array();
  headline.push("n50");
  headline.push("Number of contigs");
  dataArray.push(headline);

  for (var i = 0; i < n50.length; i++){
     var row = new Array();
     row.push(n50[i]);
     row.push(contigs[i]);
     dataArray.push(row);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I generate a HTML document in my Groovy script so the code you is JavaScript, I just imported the data from Groovy.
Your code almost works. It gives me the right output, however it creates an empty element in the beginning of the array. I can't figure out why though.

Comment: change "var dataArray = [[]];" to "var dataArray = new Array();"

Comment: or from "var dataArray = [[]];" to "var dataArray = [];" if you like it more :)